Yet another AdvancedMarkerElement marker question - They are not showing
Hi all new here and sort of new to JS.  I  have an app that's been in use for 10+years and still being used.  It in PHP/Mysql/JS and uses GM for delivery locations.  I thought I'd upgrade it to the new marker system but can't get it to work.  I think it's just me and my limited understanding of JS.
Anyway, the following code shows the map but not the markers. The rfap3 etc are based on a CSS tag.  Any help very appreciated.  Could really find any existing posts that helped me.
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=Function.prototype&key=MYKEY&loading=async"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
async function initmap() {
  // setTimeout second value is milliseconds
  // ie: 1000 = 1 second, 30000 = 30 seconds
  setTimeout( "document.location = document.location;", 30000);
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.439068, 147.135773);
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  const myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 18,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapId: 'rfamaps123456'
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("show_map"), myOptions);

  var rfastodo = [
    ['3055',-41.416744,147.134476,'rfap3',201],
    ['3082',-41.432907,147.152039,'rfap3',202],
    ['3079',-41.431507,147.147400,'rfap2',203]
  ];
  
setRFAs(map, rfastodo);

  function setRFAs(map, rfalist){
      const rfaTag = document.createElement("div");
      for (var i = 0; i < rfalist.length; i++) {
        var rfas = rfalist[i];
        var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(rfas[1], rfas[2]);
        rfaTag.classname = rfas[3];
        rfaTag.textcontent = rfas[0];
        var marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
          position: myLatLng2,
          map: map,
          content: rfaTag,
          zIndex: rfas[4]
        });
      }
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
</script>

Just finding that everything is there except the markers.

Any errors in the console?

No errors are being reported.

I wonder if it's because you pass the same div to all markers - and it is empty because you use rfaTag.textcontent rather than rfaTag.textContent

Also, shouldn't the bounds.extends be inside the for loop? Also, rfaTag.classname should be rfaTag.className

Thanks jaromanda.  We have progress.  Changing the C and N fixed part.  I know have one marker up, the last one only.  So the others are being over written somehow.  I also move the fitbounds to inside the loop but as there is only one marker I doesn't show any different.  I'll see if I can hard code the rfaTag part.

move const rfaTag = document.createElement("div"); INSIDE the for loop

You have multiple issues in your setRFAs function
  // this should be inside the for loop
  const rfaTag = document.createElement("div");

and
    rfaTag.classname = rfas[3]; // this should be className
    rfaTag.textcontent = rfas[0]; // this should be textContent

and
  // this should be inside the for loop
  bounds.extend(marker.position);

With the fixes as per above, the function looks like:
function setRFAs(map, rfalist) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rfalist.length; i++) {
    const rfaTag = document.createElement("div");
    var rfas = rfalist[i];
    var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(rfas[1], rfas[2]);
    rfaTag.classBame = rfas[3];
    rfaTag.textContent = rfas[0];
    var marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
      position: myLatLng2,
      map: map,
      content: rfaTag,
      zIndex: rfas[4]
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

as a bonus - I'd write it like
function setRFAs(rfaList) {
  rfaList.forEach(([textContent, lat, lng, className, zIndex]) => {
      const content = document.createElement("div");
      content.className = className;
      content.textContent = textContent;
      position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position, map, content, zIndex});
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
    }
  );
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

and call it without the map argument, since that's just like how you don't call it with bounds, you just use bounds from the outer scope anyway

We are a goer!  Thank you so much Jaromanda X  and I've learnt a bit (I hope :-)
